# Validate HTML5 date input with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm using [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin to validate my form. All works fine, including nice layout for showing errors.

Now we are have in issue with date inputs that are not required. We use the HTML5 input like this:

```
<input type="date">
```

Now jQuery validation is validating this input, but it is always ok. Because:

- If I don't enter a value, it's ok because it's not required.
- If I do enter a valid date, it's ok because it's a valid date.
- If I do enter a wrong date (31-06-2016), it's ok because the element will return an empty string, same as not being filled in, and since it is not required, it is ok.

The basic HTML form validation, done by the browser catches this date error. But with jQuery validation it doesn't work anymore.

**Edit for duplicate question:**
The duplicate reffering to is going about getting the HTML5 date input working. But that's not my issue, my issue is about validation, as mentioned in the title!

**Edit**
See this jsfiddle for testen with or without jQuery validation. https://jsfiddle.net/xr56gk56/

Comment: @Danieboy, your question is not the same as mine. It's just about the HTML5 input type date. Min is in combination with jQuery validation.

Comment: What do you mean `But with jQuery validation it doesn't work anymore.`

Comment: @lolka_bolka, the validation about the invalid date is not working. Without jQuery validation the browser (Chrome) will catch the error, since 31-06-2016 does not exist. But when jQuery validation is active, the browser validation is off, all is done by jQuery validation.

Comment: Yeah afaik jquery validation turns off browser validation - I'd simply validate it without `required: true` - if you can, I presume you can

Comment: No, the value is not required, but if a value is entered, it should be correct.

Comment: What you need to do is:  if a date is selected, then validate if it's an actual date, else do nothing

Comment: @FreshPro, that's what I wanted to do. But when an invalid date is entered, it also acts like no date is entered.